# Node JS: Named callback functions and Garbage collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

```
process.on('an event', function () {
    setTimeOut(function onTimeOut() {

        // ... code

    }, 5000)
})
```

Hi friends! I have two question, please advise me.

1. Will the named callback function `onTimeOut` stored at Global scope and skipped by GC?
2. If it is stored at local scope, it will re-created every time the `event` invoked (tagged to GC), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, it is stored in the closest scope just like any other variable/value. Additionally, the name will only be referenceable inside the body of that function.
2. Yes, a new callback function will be created every time the `an event` event fires.